# Non-Selective Query Exception on Task Query

Tags: trigger, soql, selectivity

I have the following three SOQL queries in a class that is being called by a Trigger. The Trigger counts the number of completed tasks and events for a given account.

```
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT ID, activity_count__c FROM Account WHERE ID IN :accountIds];
List<Task> compTasks = [SELECT ID, AccountID FROM Task WHERE Status = 'Completed' AND
                        AccountID IN :accountIds AND CreatedById NOT IN :exclusions];
List<Event> events = [SELECT ID, AccountID FROM Event WHERE AccountID IN :accountIds AND
                     CreatedById NOT IN :exclusions];
```

Periodically, I'm getting a 'caused by: System.QueryException: Non-selective query against large object type (more than 100000 rows)' error on the compTasks query. I've learned from our admin that this occurs when Leads are converted.

In searching for a solution I found a suggestion to add 'ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 10000' since CreatedDate is an index, and it will keep my search within the bounds of the large object limit.

Should I be concerned about limiting my query to 10000? Could I potentially be missing possible tasks to count? Or, is there a better way to make my count while avoiding the Non-selective query Exception?

Comment: Not central to your question, but using an aggregate query for the Task and Event queries (i.e. with `group by AccountId` and count() in the select) would save you having to do any looping to get the counts per Account id.

Comment: That's a good point. Thanks, Keith C! Although, even using an aggregate query will still cause me to run into the Non-selective Query Exception, right?

Comment: Yeah I assume so as the same set of rows need to be found; the aggregation just returns the data ready grouped.

Comment: I'm not sure if this should be asked as a separate question, but isn't accountid an external ID and therefore indexed? In which case why is it throwing a Non-selective query error?

Comment: @RohanC I had similar thoughts. I'll post that as a separate question and see what I can discover.

Comment: Said follow up question is here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33860/is-accountid-a-standard-index-on-task-table

Answer (score 1):

Although you're querying on an indexed field, your clause needs to sufficiently reduce the number of records in the resulting data set. As SF themselves put it:

> Selective SOQL Query Criteria
>
> A query is selective when one of the
>   query filters is on an indexed field and the query filter reduces the
>   resulting number of rows below a system-defined threshold. The
>   performance of the SOQL query improves when two or more filters used
>   in the WHERE clause meet the mentioned conditions.
>
> The selectivity
>   threshold is 10% of the records for the first million records and less
>   than 5% of the records after the first million records, up to a
>   maximum of 333,000 records. In some circumstances, for example with a
>   query filter that is an indexed standard field, the threshold may be
>   higher. Also, the selectivity threshold is subject to change.

See https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm

Exactly how it all works is a bit hairy and undocumented.

An alternative approach would be to write a trigger on Task (insert, update, delete) that updates a counter on Account. i.e. Update the count as Tasks are inserted/deleted/completed rather than try to query the large dataset.

Comment: In Spring14 there's a new REST API option to see some limited details about the query plan being used. See http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_query_explain.htm